# Try to take a diff from the GitHub PR to last 5 days

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to sort the difference from the today date and last 5 days with this command.

**Command:**

```
DIFFERENCE_DAYS=$((  ($(date '+%s') - $(date '+%s' -d ${Created_Date})) / 86400  ))
```

**Getting this error:**

```
find PR older than 5days and delete from repo
 Branch name: "pull-req5" 
 PR created at date: "2022-05-26T17:50:36Z" 
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnRu] [-r seconds|file] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]]
            [-I[date | hours | minutes | seconds]]
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
./git_personal_repo.sh: line 47: (f - ) / 86400  : syntax error: operand expected (error token is ") / 86400  ")
```